# How to make this layout work on all screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tricky CSS requirement. Inside a Bootstrap column, I need to place 2 equal **squares** in a row, and there are 3 bits of text inside each one. This was easy enough at first, but it is proving very difficult to adapt to different screen sizes - mainly because the font size is a huge factor.

Here is what it looks like on my screen, and basically how it should look (only scaled) on bigger and smaller screens:

[image]

Here is the current HTML:

```
<div class="row basic-ratings-layout">
    <div class="col-md-6 no-stretch"><div class="stock-rating negative"><div class="stock-rating-inner">
                            Shares <span class="stock-rating-unit">- Mil</span> <div class="stock-rating-start-end"><div>490.68</div> <div>to</div> <div>892.46</div></div> <div class="stock-rating-change">
                                increased by 81.88%
                            </div></div></div></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 no-stretch"><div class="stock-rating negative"><div class="stock-rating-inner">
                            Margin % <span class="stock-rating-unit"></span> <div class="stock-rating-start-end"><div>5.50</div> <div>to</div> <div>2.25</div></div> <div class="stock-rating-change">
                                decreased by 59.09%
                            </div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

And the current CSS (using SASS):

```
.basic-ratings-layout {
    .col-md-6 {
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      .stock-rating {
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
        .stock-rating-inner {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 0;
          .stock-rating-change {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
            font-size: 0.8em;
          }
          .stock-rating-unit {
            font-size: 0.8em;
            opacity: 0.7;
          }
          .stock-rating-start-end {
            font-size: 1.1em;
            line-height: 1.4;
            padding-top: 10%;
          }
        }
        &.negative {
          border: 2px solid $red;
          .stock-rating-change {
            color: $red;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is twofold:

1. scaling the font size so that it always fits nicely (especially preventing the bottom line from spilling over)
2. keeping it aligned vertically - the middle part shifts up and down depending on the screen size

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What about SVG? If each box, along with its content, is an SVG, the browser will mostly treat them as it does with images but you'll still have the ability to change them the same as you would HTML.

Comment: @Ouroborus I'd much prefer to not have SVG if not necessary.

Comment: As you've probably noticed, Bootstrap on its own doesn't really handle what you want. Doing the general layout is likely possible with careful use of `display:grid;` and associated. The bigger problem is trying to get the text's width to fit the container. There's no built in way to do that so it'll have to be a hack by either: 1) tying the font size to `vw` units so it maps to the view width, or 2) using javascript to measure the width of the text and dynamically scaling the font-size accordingly.

Comment: @Ouroborus What about the vertical alignment of the middle text section? If I can get that to always remain centered vertically, I can hack the font size issue one way or another.

Comment: Maybe something like https://jsfiddle.net/ouroborus/p4n57fce/

Comment: @Ouroborus Sorry, but I don't see how this solves the vertical space problem. I mean, it works great with this size of the box and fonts, but the whole point is responsiveness...

Comment: There's one width and one font size to change as needed. Everything else follows from that. That width and font size can be made relative or computed (for example, via `calc()` or `var()`).